# Error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when Embed Unity(Vuforia) in IOS project(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I am trying to embed a Unity project(with Vuforia and map box) in an existing IOS project. I followed steps from :

- https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5
- https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity
- https://the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/

However, at the end, I am getting errors `undefined symbols for architecture arm64`, and  seems like it has trouble with `libVuforiaWrapper.a` which is a unity file.

The detailed error is following:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ericquan/Desktop/UnityAppDemo/AppDemo/../UnityIOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS'


Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[NSData(GZIP) mme_gunzippedData] in libMapboxMobileEventsStatic.a(NSData+MMEGZIP.o)

"Vuforia::MetalRenderData::MetalRenderData()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_PlatformiOS.mm in libVuforiaWrapper.a(PlatformiOS.o)


 (maybe you meant: _unity_z_inflateInit2_, _il2cpp_z_inflateInit2_ )
```

Xcode version: 9.4.1

Unity version: 2018.1.0f2

other: Vuforia is used in unity project

Trials:

1. In build setting, changing the architecture arm64 to armv7 armv7s.
2. reimporting libVuforiaWrapper.a

I have stuck on this point for one day, is there anyone willing to help? Thank you!!!!

Comment: Did you fixed this? any solution please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. You have to add a Vuforia.framework on your project.

look at this website to get an basic idea to use vuforia.framework

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-iOS-Development.html

and for working on your project, you should go website below and follow the steps in section "building in Xcode"

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/how-migrate-vuforia-7_2.html

Comment: Could you give some more details on what you did to get this working? I have tried adding vuforia.framework into my xcode project but still can't get it to work